# jquery event binding to all text elements in a div

Tags: jquery, events, binding, selector

I have a div that contains some texts and spans. I want to capture all mouseup/keyup on the texts, and all dblclick on the spans. the problem is that the mouseup/keyup is getting fired before the dblclick. see my code below:

```
<div>text1 text2 <span>text3</span> text4 <span>text5</span>

span {background:grey}

$("div").on("keyup mouseup", function () {
    alert("div keyup mouseup");
});
$("span").on("dblclick", function (event) {
    alert("span dblclick");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RfpvP/

one of the solutions could be to bind the onmouseup/onkeyup only to text elements. I wonder how can I do that with jquery. something on the lines of :

```
$("div").on("keyup mouseup", "text-only-selector", function () {
    alert("div keyup mouseup");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prevent the event propagation from the span element

```
$("div").on("keyup mouseup", function () {
    console.log("div keyup mouseup");
});
$("span").on("dblclick", function (event) {
    console.log("span dblclick");
});
$("span").on("keyup mouseup", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M6eKE/)